# pass external config file to docker container at runtime

Tags: scala, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, sbt-native-packager

I have a scala sbt application and have a default application.conf.
I built a docker image to run this application via docker.
How can I replace the default `application.conf` in the docker container at a run time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend instead of passing `application.conf` file with overrides, go with overrides based on environment variables, because of reasons like:

- Mounting volume with configuration file might be tricky from deployment tools perspective;
- Not all configurations management tools (for instance HashiCorp Consul) provide HOCON support, but managing environment variables is almost a standard. Especially if it contains secrets which needs to be protected;

So, you can do next:
In your application conf set overrides via environment variable:

```
foo=default
foo={?FOO}
```

And run application docker container with specific override:

```
docker run ...
 -e foo=bar \
 ...
```

Please, see for more details:

- HOCON `Optional system or env variable overrides`: https://github.com/lightbend/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides
- Run docker container with environment variables: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

Hope this helps!